# Select2 not working on Kendo UI Window

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, jquery-select2

I am trying to use **Select2** plugin on **Kendo Window**. But its not working for me. ComboBox content is not visible when trying to open that.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just need to `select2.css` class `select2-drop` changed the `z-index` and it works just fine

```
.select2-drop {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10010;
    top: 100%;

    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-top: 0;

    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
            box-shadow: 0 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}
```